# kdiff3 how to compare files over remote server ftp?

Tags: server, ftp, remote

I followed the instructions from here

http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/misc.html

But i can't make it working. For some reason the kdiff always throw an error it's not a file.

How can i compare the file differences between my pc and remote server. I want to check if someone tempered with the files on the server. Or if kdiff can't make it do you have any suggestions for other software ?